# How to save record if internet connection unavailable? (or how to save via CKOperation)

Tags: objective-c, ios8, xcode6

What is the proper way to save records to my apps database, when no internet connection or LTE/3G?

Also for modify and delete the record?

Any answers would be appreciated! ;)

Answer (score 1):

From [CloudKit Framework Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CloudKit/Reference/CloudKit_Framework_Reference/):
"Because it provides minimal offline caching support, CloudKit relies on the presence of the network and optionally a valid iCloud account"

In short, CloudKit is a connected API, if you need some offline cache, you have to provide it yourself (and remember to do the actual network operation later).

Comment: So, should I use CKOperation for that?

Comment: "For that" is a little bit vague. Use CloudKit to update the database in the cloud, use some local storage API (sqlite) to have store your offline database.